# upper bound and a lower bound on the number of points that are uniformly distributed on a surface

Tags: metric-geometry, probability-distributions, discrete-geometry

Can I calculate an upper bound and a lower bound (or max or min) on the number of points that are uniformly distributed on a surface, knowing the area of the surface ?

More precisely, I have a sector of a disk in the shape of a pizza slice. I tile its surface using identical size hexagons. Because of the properties of the tiling, I know that the distance between the centers of any two adjacent hexagons is the same distance r where r is known. So, I guess I can say that the centers of hexagons are uniformly distributed (or equidistributed) on the surface of the pizza slice.

In this case can I calculate the maximum and minimum number of the centers of the hexagons that can be found on the surface of the pizza slice knowing the area of the pizza slice? or at least can I find some upper and lower bounds on the number of centers of hexagons?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by having a finite set of uniformly distributed points on a surface? An example of a definition that works in a metric setting: Let $s,r>0$ be two numbers. A set of points $F\subset M$ is $(r,s)$-uniformly distributed on $M$ if $M\subset\bigcup_{x\in F}B(x,r)$ and $d(x,y)>s$ for all $x\neq y\in F$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta:not sure if I understood your question. As I explained, I need to calculate the upper bound and lower bounds for the number of the centers of hexagons that tile a surface of shape of a pizza slice. The distance between the centers of any two adjacent hexagon is known. The area of the pizza slice is also known.

Comment: Your question made me think that you wanted to study more general surfaces as well, so that hexagons wouldn't make sense anymore. It might be clearer to speak about planar domains (or something of the kind) rather than surfaces if you are not interested in curved things.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: no, I would like to just solve this problem and I should use only hexagon tiling.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following question and its answer, from which I've restated the answer.

[gauss circle problem on a hexagonal lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109515/the-gauss-circle-problem-on-a-hexagonal-lattice)

Basically the answer is known for any regular crystallographic group, it seems. For your case, the number for a circle of radius $r$ and sector angle $\theta$ would seem to be
$$
N(r;\theta,x,x_0)= \frac{\theta r^2}{\sqrt{3}} + O(r^{2/3} ),
$$
as $r\to+\infty.$

**Remark:** This assumes a lattice point is at the origin, at which the circle out of which we're cutting a sector of angle $\theta$ is also centred.

Comment: :thanks very much for your reply, just what do you mean by lattice point? I am only interested in the number of the hexagon centers, it seem that lattice points are not the same as the centers of hexagons. And yes, one of the hexagons in the hexagonal tiling is centered at the center of the disk out of which we're cutting a sector.

Comment: ok, I read the link it says that:√3/2. why did you multiply it by $\pi$

Comment: Main term was $\pi r^2/|F|$ for the full circle with $2\pi$ radians so I should have multiplied by $\theta$ and divided by $2\pi,$ sorry, I'll fix it.

Comment: according to the link: $\mid F \mid= \sqrt{3}/2$. Then, if you multiply $\pi r^2/\mid F \mid$ by $\theta/2\pi$ you should have $\frac{\theta r^2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot/too late at night here.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help :)! in this formula we assume the distance between the closest lattice point pairs is unit.What happens to the formula if the distance between the closest lattice point pairs is $R$. Can I scale it somehow?

Comment: Well, you'll need to at least recompute the fundamental domain. The original paper cited would have to be consulted to see if anything else needs changing. Perhaps you can do numerical experiments to see if this hunch that nothing else needs changing is correct.